# Why did my /var directory disappear after running mv var var?

Tags: macos, bash, mv

I accidentally ran the command "mv var var" (instead of "mv var var.bak"). Now my var directroy has disappeared. It's not in "/" anymore. Does anyone know what happens when entering this command. Where dit my var directory go?

I would say it would rename var to var, but it didn't. Maybe it tried to move var into itself or something?

**Problem is fixed**: "mv var var" is what i ran. OSX normally has a symlink to /private/var. Somehow the command removed the symlink to /private/var, so i rebooted in single-user mode (since i couldn't use sudo anymore) , and restored the symlink with ln -s /private/var /var

Comment: `mv foo foo` would return an error ("cannot move 'foo' to a subdirectory of itself, 'foo/foo'"). That's probably not exactly what you ran.

Comment: This is peculiar because if you try to move a directory to its self (which is what you are saying you did):

    [mstanislav@pardalislabs ~]$ mkdir test
    [mstanislav@pardalislabs ~]$ mv test test
    mv: cannot move `test' to a subdirectory of itself, `test/test'

Comment: Well it's strange indeed. I am on OSX. Maybe somehow my var directory is corrupt. I tried to run fsck, but i can't have sudo access, because it needs /var. What could i do to get root-access, which is disabled by default in OSX?

Comment: Try `ls -la`, in case you did `mv var var .bak` or mv `var .var`, and created a hidden directory.

Comment: Please copy and paste the entire command, including your prompt, so we can see what was run.

Comment: Type `history` to see a list of commands that you've typed, then you can copy and paste the exact command.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, I suggest you answer it yourself and select that answer as the correct one.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Darwin Mac OS X, /var is actually a symlink to /private/var, so just `ln -s /private/var /var`

Additional explanation:  You actually mv'd the symlink into /private/var, so if you `ls /private/var` you'll see the `var -> private/var` symlink inside.

Comment: This is the right answer indeed.